# Get paragraph alignment value

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to get the value of the paragraph alignment to put in the IF condition. The example below fails and does not run

Here is the code

```js
const paragraph = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for (let i = 0; i < paragraph.length; i++) {
    if (paragraph[i].getAttribute('align').value == 'center') {
        console.log('paragraph' + i + 'centered')
    }
}
```

```html
<p align="center">this is a paragraph!</p>
```

As you have noted, the value property does not exist in the attribute. How can I get the value of align, whether it is "center, left, right .."?

Comment: Just remove the .value from .getAttribute('align').value - you want if (paragraph[i].getAttribute('align') == 'center')

Comment: Don't use `align` at all. It's obsolete, and **not supported** in HTML5. Use CSS instead.

Comment: Cool, here is working. I'm learning JavaScript, maybe the question was too simple

Comment: Please see the updated answer. @Obsidian is absolutely right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const paragraph = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for (let i = 0; i < paragraph.length; i++) {
    if (paragraph[i].getAttribute('align') == 'center') {
        console.log('paragraph' + i + 'centered')
    }
}
```

```html
<p align="center">this is a paragraph!</p>
```

But the `align` attribute is old and deprecated. It's better to use `text-align` even if it is more code to read the styles.

```js
const paragraph = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

for (let i = 0; i < paragraph.length; i++) {
  let computed = window.getComputedStyle(paragraph[i], null);
  let alignment = computed.getPropertyValue('text-align')
  if (alignment == 'center') {
    console.log('paragraph' + i + 'centered')
  }
}
```

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p>this is a paragraph!</p>
```